# How to change a url of the list's view via client model?

Tags: client-object-model, list-view, view

I know how to create a view via `ViewCreationInformation` class using `client SP model`. But how I can specify a url for this view ? Is it possible ?

In other words:

```
var test = _list.Views.GetByTitle("desiredView");
ClientContext.Load(test, t=>t.Title, t=>t.Id, t=>t.ServerRelativeUrl);
ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

[ServerRelativeUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.view.serverrelativeurl.aspx) has only getter unfortunately

Comment: Append your List url with newly created view name. Like, https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/Testsite/Lists/LISTNAME/View_Name.aspx

Comment: but i just want to change a url for view

Comment: Get list url by "_list.RootFolder.Name". Then append it with "desiredView" name. May be this will help.

Comment: Yes, you are right. View's url usually looks like that. But my question is how to change this ulr programmatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`View`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.view.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) `Url` could be updated like this via CSOM API:

```
var viewPageUrl = "/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"; //existing view page url
var viewPageUrlNew = "/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItemsNEW.aspx";

var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);   
var view = list.Views.GetByTitle(viewTitle);        
var page = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(viewPageUrl);
page.MoveTo(viewPageUrlNew,MoveOperations.Overwrite);
view.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```